# Can we have more difference between the current tab and others on the "tagged" pages?

Tags: feature-request, design

Jin,

I managed to confuse myself today as I couldn't tell which tab was active on the "tagged" page:

[image]

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages

Can the current tab be shown in red or something?